# how do I add jre from java 12.0.2 to eclipse mars 4.5.2

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed java jdk 12.0.2 and eclipse on my windows 10 laptop and I am not able to add the JRE library to Eclipse Mars.2 4.5.2.

I've tried adding the library through the build path but I keep getting error saying

> Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]'.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You need Eclipse 2019-06 for full Java 12 support, Mars is far too old.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-12-support-eclipse-2019-03-411):

> This marketplace solution provides Java 12 support for Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11). To install the feature, please ensure you have the 4.11 version of Eclipse IDE installed:

Typically, such marketplace entries exist to enable a newer Java with some *older* version of eclipse.

Note: it says you need eclipse version 4.11.

**Mars** version number is **4.5**. (4.11 is the version of eclipse that was released in March 19, there is only **one** newer version, 4.12 from June 2019). And as user [greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) correctly points out, eclipse 4.12 supports Java 12 out of the box. Which again underlines my point: when you want to use the latest greatest language versions, use the latest greatest tool versions.

In other words: forget about it. Do not waste a single second trying to convince a 4 year old version of eclipse to run with a brand new Java.

Keep in mind: eclipse has its own compiler. It offers syntax support for new language features, it probably has special handling for new "things" inside java. Even if you could somehow get Mars to work with Java 12, most likely, that would be a dirty hack.

As said: consider your idea to be a waste of time. Go, get the latest version of eclipse, and use that.

( Or, my personal two cent: if you only care about Java development, go get the latest version of IntelliJ, and forget about eclipse )

Comment: Note: Eclipse 2019-06 (the current version) supports Java 12 without patches.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you, duly noted!